# How to add the custom information with the push notification using the 'Notificato' plugin?

Tags: ios, cakephp

I am sending push notifications from php job application to iphone. I am sending push notifications regarding new jobs. Is this possible that when user click on the view of push notification pop up , then user redirect to the particular job in the device.

I mean I wanted to know can I send any custom data with push notification like access_token, something else....so that Iphone end Can retrieve and show the particular job ?

Regardless of the language and library you use, the push notification payload is a JSON payload:

```
{
    "aps": {
        "badge": 10,
        "alert": "Hello world!",
        "sound": "cat.caf"
    }
}
```

We want add custom information with the push notification. Like below

```
{
    "aps": {
        "badge": 10,
        "alert": "Hello world!",
        "sound": "cat.caf"
    },
    "access_token": 1
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Finally, find the solution, How to add custom information with the push notification...

Answer (score 0):

Finally, find the solution, How to add custom information with the push notification...   We can add the custom information using the setPayload().  The apnspush() class file like this

```
<?php namespace Notificato\apnspush;
// This imports the Composer autoloader
require ROOT . "/vendor/autoload.php";
use Wrep\Notificato\Notificato;

class apnspush
{
    /**
     * This example sends one pushnotification with an alert to Apples production push servers
     */
    public function sendOnePushNotification($deviceToken,$message,$accessToken)
    {


        $passphrase = 'asded333';

   // First we get a Notificato instance and tell it what certificate to use as default certificate

        $notificato = new Notificato("CBDEV.pem",$passphrase);

        // Now we get a fresh messagebuilder from Notificato
        //  This message will be send to device with pushtoken 'fffff...'
        //  it will automaticly be associated with the default certificate
        //  and we will set the red badge on the App icon to 1

/* Make the JSON with access_token */
        $pays = ["access_token"=>$accessToken];

        $message = $notificato->messageBuilder()
                                ->setDeviceToken($deviceToken)
                                 ->setAlert($message)  
                                ->setBadge($badge)
                                ->setPayload($pays)
                                ->setSound()
                                ->build();

        // The message is ready, let's send it!
        //  Be aware that this method is blocking and on failure Notificato will retry if necessary

        $messageEnvelope = $notificato->send($message);

        // The returned envelope contains usefull information about how many retries where needed and if sending succeeded
        echo $messageEnvelope->getFinalStatusDescription();
    }
}
?>
```